# When adding generic to recursive enumeration: compiler can not infer type

Tags: swift

From the example in the Swift manual under recursive enumerations, I am trying to add a generic type to an enumeration and the compiler can not infer the type of what I am passing to the evaluate function. What can I do to change the code to compile? Is this a bug or a limitation of the compiler?

```
protocol Summable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

protocol Multipliable {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

indirect enum ArithmeticExpression<T: protocol<Summable, Multipliable>> {
    case Number(T)
    case Addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
    case Multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
}

func evaluate<T>(expression: ArithmeticExpression<T>) -> T {
    switch expression {
    case .Number(let value):
        return value
    case .Addition(let left, let right):
        return evaluate(left) + evaluate(right)
    case .Multiplication(let left, let right):
        return evaluate(left) * evaluate(right)
    }
}


let five = ArithmeticExpression.Number(5)
let four = ArithmeticExpression.Number(4)
let sum = ArithmeticExpression.Addition(five, four)
let product = ArithmeticExpression.Multiplication(sum, ArithmeticExpression.Number(2))
print(evaluate(product))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer and it's pretty simple actually:

```
extension Int: Summable, Multipliable {}
```